# Unexacte parsing in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, date, datetime, simpledateformat

How to parse a string with always different formats of date (sometimes "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", or "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm" or also "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")?

If I use the following code - it fails if the string in value has other format than "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

```
public static Date test(String value) throws ... {

  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
  return df.parse(value);


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you just try to parse each specific format, catching `ParseException` and just moving onto the next format:

```
private static final String[] patterns = {
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm",
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
};

public static Date test(String value) throws ... {
    for (String pattern : patterns) {
        try {
           DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
           return df.parse(value);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
           // No-op - move onto the next pattern
        }
    }
    // Do whatever you want here - throw ParseException, or return null
}
```

That's simple, but abuses exceptions. You *could* use the more obscure `parse(String, ParsePosition)` call instead:

```
public static Date test(String value) throws ... {
    for (String pattern : patterns) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        Date date = df.parse(value, new ParsePosition(0));
        if (date != null) {
            return date;
        }
    }
    // Do whatever you want here - throw ParseException, or return null
}
```

That *may* perform better - you'd have to benchmark it to say for sure.

It's unfortunate that you have to recreate the `SimpleDateFormat` objects on each call, but that's an issue with it not being thread-safe. Another alternative is to use [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) - which is a *much* nicer API overall - but it's not very clear how you'd do the exception-free approach there. (It may well be possible, just a bit obscure again. I suspect that `DateTimeFormatter.parseInto` would be your friend here.)

Comment: and what if the new unknown pattern will come?

Comment: @Igor: Well where would it come from? (If you want something answered, it should be in your question, by the way.) You need to have a list of patterns you expect *somewhere*. You could load them from a file or a database if you really wanted to make it very dynamic.

Comment: This is a part of source code our's server application and the strings with dates in differenz formats are coming from clients (client apps on IPhones/IPads) We have had always only "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" as incoming pattern, but yesterday I saw in log also this patter "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" and error "Unparseable date..." I dont know what kind of patterns will else come to us. Our IOS Developer will fix creation of date in the next version (he will make it independend from Iphone settings), but now I should immediately correct it on server side. Of course I had to write it in my question. Sorry

Comment: @Igor: I would be very reluctant to try to write any code which would guess a format based on arbitrary data. In some cases you may well find it's ambiguous between different cultures, e.g. MM/dd/yyyy and dd/MM/yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

`DateTimeFormatterBuilder` allows building a `DateTimeFormatter` with default time units. Also, you can specify optional parts of the pattern using a square bracket or by using the `.optionalXXX` function of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd['T'][ ]HH:mm[:ss]")
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)                                                                       
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                    "2021-07-10T10:20:30",
                    "2021-07-10 10:20:30",
                    "2021-07-10T10:20",
                    "2021-07-10 10:20"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(s,  parser)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-07-10T10:20:30
2021-07-10T10:20:30
2021-07-10T10:20
2021-07-10T10:20
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/6D3iEU)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>